# print line only if number in third field is greater than X

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

The following `lsblk` command print the disk usage in bytes

```
 lsblk -bio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL| grep disk 

 sda   disk  298999349248 AVAGO
 sdb   disk 1998998994944 AVAGO
 sdc   disk 1998998994944 AVAGO
 sdd   disk 1998998994944 AVAGO
 sde   disk   98998994944 AVAGO
```

how to print the disks when disk is greater than 300000000000 , by adding after the pipe `awk` or `perl` one-liner or else

expected output:

```
 lsblk -bio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL| grep disk | ......
 sdb   disk 1998998994944 AVAGO
 sdc   disk 1998998994944 AVAGO
 sdd   disk 1998998994944 AVAGO
```

Comment: `awk '$3 >= 1998998994944' infile`  Sice your output doesn't have a disk larger than `300000000000` you won't be able to print anything. The syntax will work in general. `$3 > some_value`  then print.

Comment: I not want to work with files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with `awk` itself for pattern matching instead of using `grep`.

```
lsblk -bio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL| awk '/disk/ && $3> 300000000000 || NR==1'
```

Or use scientific value `3e11`.

Answer (score 10):

Short **Awk** approach:

```
lsblk -nbio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL | awk '$3>3e11'
```

---

- `-n` (`--noheadings`) - don't print headings
- `$3` - the 3rd field (`SIZE` column)
- `3e11` - *E*-notation.  the letter `E` (or `e`) is often used to represent "times *ten* raised to the power of" (which would be written as `"× 10n`") and is followed by the value of the exponent; in other words, for any two real numbers `m` and `n`, the usage of "`mEn`" would indicate a value of `m × 10n`. `3e11` is equivalent to `300000000000`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
lsblk -bio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL | perl -ane 'print if $F[2] > 3e11'
```

You can use 300_000_000_000 as the value also.

- `-n`  reads the input line by line without printing
- `-a` splits the input on whitespace into the @F array